# Contact form not working using php and html?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I am having problem with this contact form I can't get this to work please help?
I have tried it on my local host and on a web hosting bu nothing seem to work.

send.php

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if (isset($_GET["mrova-name"])) {
$name = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-name']);
$email = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-email']);
$message = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-message']);
$header = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">rn"; 

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$httpref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$httpagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");    

$recipient = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Advertising';
$mailbody = "
First Name: $name
Email: $email
Message: $message

IP: $ip
Browser info: $httpagent
Referral: $httpref
Sent: $today
";
$result = 'success';

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody, $header)) {
    echo json_encode($result);
}
}
?>
```

I have used  the method 'post' but it doesn't work what so ever

contact-form.html

```
<div id="mrova-feedback">

    <div id="mrova-contact-thankyou" style="display: none;">
        Thank you.  We'hv received your feedback.
    </div>
    <div id="mrova-form">
        <form id="mrova-contactform" action="css/send.php" method="post">
            <ul >

                <li>
                    <center><h2 class="mrova-contactform-head">Quick Contact</h2></center>
                    <label for="mrova-name">Your Name<font color="red">*</font></label> <input type="text" name="mrova-name" class="required" id="mrova-name" value="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="mrova-email">Email<font color="red">*</font></label> <input type="text" name="mrova-email" class="required" id="mrova-email" value="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="mrova-message">Message<font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <textarea class="required" id="mrova-message" name="mrova-message"  rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" style="button" value="Send" id="mrova-sendbutton" name="mrova-sendbutton">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="mrova-img-control"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? Have you used FireBug?

Comment: Are you receiving any error message? Can you reduce the amount of code and post here only the relevant parts?

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question? If one of the answers solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending the HTML Form as a `post` request, but reading the `$_GET` variable in php.

You have to decide for one method. Either switch to get in your HTML form, or change all `$_GET` variables into `$_POST`

For more information about the differences look [here](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Get_vs_Post).

Answer (score 0):

You are sending via **POST**..how can you access it using **GET**.
Change all `$_GET[""]` to `$_POST[""]`.
Or change the form method from **POST** to **GET**. The first one will be better.

`$_GET` is for all **GET** requests. Whereas `$_POST` is for **POST** requests. 
It depends upon the form method , how you are sending data.

Answer (score 0):

From your form, it seems like you are using $_POST.

`<form id="mrova-contactform" action="css/send.php" method="post">`

In your PHP codes, you will need to use $_POST.

`For example, $_POST["mrova-name"]`;

Answer (score 0):

Using this line will not be sent to the proper area in Email

```
$header = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">rn";
```

It needs to be changed to:

```
$header = "From: ". $name . " $email " . "\r\n";
```

`rn` need to be seperated with `\` and the `$email` without the `<` `>`

Which rewrites to: (using **POST** and not **GET** as stated in posted code)

```
if (isset($_POST["mrova-name"])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['mrova-name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['mrova-email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['mrova-message']);
$header = "From: ". $name . " $email " . "\r\n";
```

> ### Rewrite (tested)

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if (isset($_POST["mrova-name"])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['mrova-name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['mrova-email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['mrova-message']);
$header = "From: ". $name . " $email " . "\r\n"; 

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$httpref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$httpagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");    

$recipient = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Advertising';
$mailbody = "
First Name: $name
Email: $email
Message: $message

IP: $ip
Browser info: $httpagent
Referral: $httpref
Sent: $today
";
$result = 'success';

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody, $header)) {
    echo json_encode($result);
}
}
?>
```